# Loading data from database in every few seconds without page refresh

Tags: php

I want to load contents from database in every 10 seconds to a particular  . But however i try whole page gets refreshed. Not getting where oi am going wrong.

Here is my code

```
<?php 
include('header.php');
include('includes/Connection.php');
include('includes/GeneralFunctions.php');
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
      $('#test').load('#test');
 },5000);
</script>


<div id="test">
<?php
$l1 = $con->prepare("SELECT msg, topic FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC");
$l1->execute();
$cntmsg = $l1->rowCount();
foreach($l1 as $r1)
{
    echo $r1['topic']."<br />";
    echo $r1['msg']."\n";
    
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: pls put the php code into a separate PHP file. then use ajax to load it every 10 seconds onto the DIV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajax in your SetInterval function.
**ajax()** method is used to perform an AJAX (asynchronous HTTP) request

```
$.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
    $("#div1").html(result);
  }});
```

Comment: Thanks. i have done like this and it works. `$(document).ready(function(){
  sendRequest();
  function sendRequest(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "countsr.php",
        success: 
          function(data){
           $('#test1').html(data); 
           
        },
        complete: function() {
      
       setInterval(sendRequest, 2000); 
     } });  }; });`, but in place of url can't i put div name to load contents directly from db?

Comment: no you can't do that. but in ajax success method you can load div directly